# How to search a text for a pattern and extract the text-part which follows the pattern?

Tags: .net, linq

following problem:
I try to read out user names out of a textblock. I normally use .Net for this and tried it with LINQ and Regex but I cant get a solution.

The pattern for the username is 'jane.doe' (without the quotations). Right now I have the following code sequence:

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Public Class Form1
    Dim arrStrSplittet As String()
    Dim strRegEx As String = "[a-z]+[.]{1}[a-z]+"
    Dim regExKriterium As Regex = New Regex(strRegEx)

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        arrStrSplittet = stringSplitten(TextBox1.Text)
        TextBox2.Text = testFiltern(arrStrSplittet)
    End Sub

    Function testFiltern(text As String()) As String
        Dim query = From x In text Where (regExKriterium.IsMatch(x)) Select x 
        Dim strBuild As New System.Text.StringBuilder()
        For Each y As String In query
            strBuild.AppendLine(y)
        Next
        MsgBox(strBuild.ToString())
        Return strBuild.ToString()
    End Function

    Public Function stringSplitten(text As String) As String()
        Dim arrX = Split(text, vbNewLine)
        Return arrX
    End Function

End Class
```

I try the following input:

```
Type Status Name
Benutzer Mustermann, Max (Server-name\max.mustermann)
Benutzer Normalverbraucher, Otto (Server-name\otto.normalverbraucher)
Benutzer Doe, Jane (Server-name\jane.doe)
Benutzer Svensson, Kalle (Server-name\kalle.svensson)
Benutzer Borg, Joe (Server-name\joe.borg)
```

And with the Code above I get the following output:

```
Benutzer Mustermann, Max (Server-name\max.mustermann)
Benutzer Normalverbraucher, Otto (Server-name\otto.normalverbraucher)
Benutzer Doe, Jane (Server-name\jane.doe)
Benutzer Svensson, Kalle (Server-name\kalle.svensson)
Benutzer Borg, Joe (Server-name\joe.borg)
```

The output should be:

```
max.mustermann
otto.normalverbraucher
jane.doe
kalle.svensson
joe.borg
```

Is it even possible to change the Object x in the LINQ? Does someone has another idea how to solve this? Currently I have a working (but pretty ugly) solution via InStr.

I hope someone can help me. Thanks in advance!
Misao

Answer (score 0):

The solutions you have so far are complete overkill. `Regex.Match` will return captures, you specify them with `()`

```cs
Dim users = lines
    .Select(Function(l) Regex.Match(l, "\(.+?\\(.+?)\)"))
    .Where(Function(m) m.Success)
    .Select(Function (m) m.Groups(1).Captures(0).Value)
    .ToList()
```

The Regex goes as follows

- `\(` an escaped open parenthesis
- `.+?` any characters, lazy match (the minimum possible)
- `\\` an escaped backslash
- `(` begins a capture
- `.+?` any characters
- `)` ends the capture
- `\)` an escaped closing parenthesis

[**VB dotnetfiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/bOXQIG)

[**C# dotnetfiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/IaPQ7A)